# FFMPEG Keyframes Exception

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I was hoping someone could help me, when pulling keyframes from a .mp4 file using FFMPEG in python I get this error:

```
     C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Coll. Detection/UAS_Detection/GUI.py"
in GUI main
('filePath', PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'C:\\Users\\Razor\\Downloads\\video_test_512kb.mp4'), '\n')
File Path -> C:\Users\Razor\Downloads\video_test_512kb.mp4
SingleDetect C:\Users\Razor\Downloads\video_test_512kb.mp4
ffmpeg version N-84679-gd65b595 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 51.100 / 55. 51.100
  libavcodec     57. 86.103 / 57. 86.103
  libavformat    57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavdevice    57.  3.101 / 57.  3.101
  libavfilter     6. 78.100 /  6. 78.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Razor\Downloads\video_test_512kb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    title           : test file mp4 - http://www.archive.org/details/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4
    encoder         : Lavf51.10.0
    comment         : license:  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/
  Duration: 00:00:16.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 562 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 512 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 45 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000000003500e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'tmp/%d.jpeg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    comment         : license:  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/
    title           : test file mp4 - http://www.archive.org/details/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4
    encoder         : Lavf57.67.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.86.103 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
2017-04-02 18:36:07.832000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Detection.py", line 59, in <module>
    draw_detections(frame, found)
  File "Detection.py", line 32, in draw_detections
    result = Result.objects.create(picture=img, x=x, y=y, w=w, h=h)
AttributeError: type object 'Result' has no attribute 'objects'
frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=19.3 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:16.06 bitrate=N/A speed= 191x    
video:160kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm trying to run these keyframes through an opencv human shape recognition api. It saves close to 300 keyframes to the folder I specified but for some reason the program just hangs afterwords instead of running the open cv hogger api on the newly saved keyframes. Will post script if it will help. Thank you for any help you can provide!!!

Comment: Don't see any errors in the text you provided

Comment: My apologies, the wrong run was on my clipboard. The one with errors is now up.